# Django shared variable from models

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class Tipo(models.Model):
   code=  models.TextField()

   def thename(self):
        from myhelp import Diz_Tipi
        return Diz_tipi[self.code]
```

**myhelp.py**

```
def creatediz():
        return dict_Tipi

Diz_Tipi=creatediz()
```

This works but I don't think *from myhelp import Diz_Tipi* should be in that place.
If I add at the start of models.py it return:

> File
>   "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 131, in check_models_ready
>       raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")

there is any other way to make Diz_Tipi available from all the modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a circular dependency issue.

Note that the error says `"Models aren't loaded yet."`.

So, are you trying to import one of your models in `myhelp`? If so, that would create a circular dependency problem, because `models.py` is importing from `myhelp.py` and `myhelp.py` is importing from `models.py`.

Answer (score 0):

there is a strange issue in django I faced with this, I would add the following to the top of the file:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

this in turn should load your apps before attempting model access, also make sure that the app that contains the models file is in the installed apps file in settings